# Java while loop and random method

Tags: java, loops, random

I'm currently learning Java and learning while loop right now. How could I used the random() method to generate random negative number? Also, how do I make the program print out value that fall only in a certain range? For example Let say Java choose 10 random numbers, how could I make it so it only display number between 0.6 and 0.8?

```
 double randomNumber;
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter <= 99)
    {
        randomNumber = Math.random();
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
         counter++;
```

Comment: For better help sooner 1) post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One question per ..question, preferably including what you think the answer is, and why.  As general tips:  Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks to help make the logic flow more obvious.  Show some effort at solving the specific question.

Comment: randomNumber * -1? Thanks
@Andrew, thanks for the tips.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - to get a negative random number. Though truely it would need to be `-1.0d` if you were mucking about with the raw `double`, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *get* a random number in that range:

```
double r = Math.random(); // -> [0, 1)
r = r * 0.2;              // scale     -> [0, 0.2)
r = r + 0.6;              // translate -> [0.6, 0.8)
```

(Similar math can be done to create negative numbers or map to an arbitrary range.)

To "only do something" with a number if it is already in that range:

```
double r = Math.random(); // -> [0, 1)
if (r >= 0.6 && r < 0.8) {
    // r -> [0.6, 0.8)
} else {
    // r -> not in above range
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Math.random()` gives you a number between 0.0, inclusive, and 1.0, exclusive, so the traditional way of getting some other range is to multiply by the width of your range and add the bottom of your range to it. Thus:

```
Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.6
```

would give you something in [0.6, 0.8).

Comment: Do I just add the *0.2 + 0.6 to my Math.random()? It not displaying value between 0.6 and 0.8 for me.

Comment: If you put the code I posted in a `System.out.println(...)`, it would print a number in the given range.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want negative numbers only, or combined. For negative only, just multiply by `-1.0d`:

```
double random = Math.random() * -1.0f; // range ]-1, 0]
```

For combined, positive and negative, use:

```
double random = 2.0d * (Math.random() - 0.5d); // range [-1, 1[
```

---

And for the second question, use a simple if:

```
double random = 2.0d * (Math.random() - 0.5d);
if (0.6d < random && random < 0.8d)
{
     System.out.println(random);
}
```

Comment: *"for the second question"* ..it would be better to scale the value to within the range, in case it later becomes .00006 to .00008.  ;)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know why he would be asking for random negative values at the same time, since 0.6 and 0.8 are both positive. And if I strictly interpret his question, he says "*only **display** numbers between 0.6 and 0.8*" and not "generate".

Comment: Would I need to initialize varible "random" before it can be used in the 2nd question? Thanks

@ Martijin, sorry for the confusion it was two question. What I meant to put was a question on how to display negative number instead of postive and  the second question was how to display number only in a certain range.

Comment: Not sure what causes the confusion, but I edited my answer. Hopefully clearer now.